# subtraction from a list in python

Tags: python

I would like to identify the difference of one number and another, I tried subtraction, but to work with subtraction would have to be two by two, because the return has to be 1, if the return is two, it will have an action. Would you have a suggestion for me to check the sequence of these numbers?

```
sql = """ SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(ARQUIVO_XML,10,6)
            FROM NOW.TB_SVOD_CONSUMIDO_NET
            WHERE DT_CADASTRO = CURRENT_DATE
            AND SMARTCARD <> 'NOWONLINE'
            ORDER BY 1 """

c.execute(sql)
resultSet = c.fetchall()

for contAq in resultSet:
    print(contAq)
    xml = contAq[0]
    total -= int(xml)
    print(total)
```

Comment: Can you please post what a `resultSet` looks like, in addition to what results you are currently getting, and what results you would ideally get?

Comment: What does `Would you have a suggestion for me to check the sequence of these numbers?` mean?

Comment: ('079171',)
('079172',)
('079173',)
('079174',)
('079175',)
('079176',)
('079177',)
('079179',)
('079181',)
('079182',)
('079183',)
('079184',)
('079185',)
('079186',)
('079187',)
('079188',)
('079189',)
('079190',)
('079191',)
('079192',)
('079193',)
('079194',)
I would like to validate the sequence of these files, because it is sequential, initially I had the idea of ​​subtracting, but if you have another, I'm open to learn, thanks in advance for the collaboration

Comment: Would you have a suggestion for me to check the sequence of these numbers? - yes

Comment: You can use this: 

    for contAq in resultSet:
        for number in contAq:
            print(number)

You can also use, and i think it's better, [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Not sure if this helps you.